# DisplayTime of Advanced Tooltip doesn't work

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, tooltip

I'm using 
http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com/

and I have a problem with this control because whatever value I set : 2 or 60 seconds, tooltip always me only for 10 seconds.

Is t related to telerik, or I use it incorrect?

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerDetail}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Customer Detail" Width="0.8*" >
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerDetail}" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <Controls:ToolTip InitialDelay="00:00:05" DisplayTime="00:00:02">
                        <Controls:ToolTip.Content>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerDetails}"/>  
                        </Controls:ToolTip.Content>
                    </Controls:ToolTip>
                                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your InitialDelay and DisplayTime are incorrect - should be in milliseconds.

Try:

```
<Controls:ToolTip InitialDelay="5000" DisplayTime="2000">
                    <Controls:ToolTip.Content>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerDetails}"/>  
                    </Controls:ToolTip.Content>
                </Controls:ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're still using the default ToolTipService provider, your code reads

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
..
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

Should it read?

```
<Controls:ToolTipService.ToolTip>
...
</Controls:ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

Comment: Tough to troubleshoot that without more code.. I haven't used the Telerik controls. Could you try implementing the custom tooltip in a more simple example without the GridView control wrapping it to ensure you've got the right way of doing things. Also does the CustomerDetails property ever get evaluated (can you drop a breakpoint on it?).